# RxSwift - How to concatenate observables of collection

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm trying to concatenate two observables of collection with `concat()` operator, however, it's not working as expected.

I've two observables:

```
let first = Observable<[Int]>.create { observer in
    observer.onNext([1, 2])
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}

let second = PublishSubject<[Int]>()
```

Using `concat()`:

```
let items = Observable.concat([first, second])

items.subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0)
})

second.onNext([3, 4, 5])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
```

What I want:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't *just* want to concat two observables, you *also* want to concat the arrays that are in the events that are produced by the two observables. You aren't going far enough to get what you want.

Imagine you had two Array<[Int]> instead of two Observable<[Int]>. Concat-ing the two (as in arr1 + arr2) would not produce `[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`, instead it would produce [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]. Your Observables are behaving the same way.

To both concat *and* combine them, you need `scan`, as in:

```
let items = Observable.concat([first, second])
    .scan([], accumulator: +)
```

Which will produce two events:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

FYI, with arrays, we don't have a scan operator, but we can approximate it with reduce. For arrays, it would be:

```
let arr1: Array<[Int]> = [[1, 2]]
let arr2: Array<[Int]> = [[3, 4, 5]]
let itemsArr = (arr1 + arr2).reduce([], { result, element in
    return result + [(result.last ?? []) + element]
})
print(itemsArr)
```

Comment: Worked. I made it work by using `combineLatest(first, second)` and then concat first with combined observable. Your solution is cleaner and I'd explore `scan()`

Comment: The two solutions behave the same for the first set of events, but completely different for subsequent events. Use the one that behaves the way you want.